# The best best way to solve double integral

Tags: calculus

I am new to calculus. There is a solution I don't understand the step.
The question requires to do the following integral.
$$
\int_1^3 \int_{-2}^2 \frac{x^{2015}}{y}dxdy
$$

Instead of doing the integral with respect to dx first, it breaks it to this

$$
\int_{-2}^2 x^{2015}dx \cdot\int_1^3 \frac{1}{y}dy
$$

I am not sure why it works. It gets the same answer which is 0.

Comment: The integral is $0$ but you cannot interchange the integrals. The integral w.r.t $y$ is $\infty$.

Comment: I change the upper and lower limits. My bad

Comment: something looks wrong, (you should have just one $y$). Integrating w.r.t $x$ is the easiest. (odd function, integrated between $[-2,2]$ is always 0)

Comment: That *IS* doing the $x$ integral first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can think of this as two steps of moving a constant expression (one that does not depend on the integration variable) out of the integrand.

$$
\begin{align}
\int_1^3 \int_{-2}^2 \frac{x^{2015}}{y}dxdy
&=\int_1^3 \int_{-2}^2 \left(\frac1y\right)x^{2015}dxdy\\
&=\int_1^3 \frac1y\left(\int_{-2}^2 x^{2015}dx\right)dy\\
&=\left(\int_{-2}^2 x^{2015}dx\right)\int_1^3 \frac1ydy.\\
\end{align}
$$

Note that $\frac1y$ does not depend on $x$ and $\int_{-2}^2 x^{2015}dx$ does not depend on $y$.

Comment: So this is not always true?

Comment: What do you mean by "this"?

Comment: taking out the x integral

Comment: The point is that the $x$ integral is just some number that doesn't depend on $y$, so you can take it out of the $y$ integral.